# Nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance in swift

Tags: swift3, nib, custom-cell

I'm using a custom `CustomTableViewCell`. When I try to run my code, I got this exception stack and I can't understand the source of the problem:

```
terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'invalid nib registered for identifier (ID) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance'
```

In CustomTableViewCell has two cells in one xib file, and i have given different identifiers

**Some piece of code**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

let nib = UINib(nibName:"CustomTableViewCell", bundle:nil)
tableview.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier:"ID")
tableview.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier:"ID2")

}
```

after that

```
func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {

    if indexPath.row == 0
    {

     let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"ID") as! CustomTableViewCell

                cell.textLabel.text = "TEXT"
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = "DETAIL TEXT"

         return cell
     }
else
    {
    let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"ID2") as! CustomTableViewCell

                cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named:"image.png")

    return cell

    }

  }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have created `UITableViewCell` as xib file ? It must be your XIB file name.

Comment: @JanakNirmal yes, i have created as xib file

Comment: @JanakNirmal, can u help me?

Comment: what is the name of that xib file ? you need to put that file name instead of `UITableViewCell`

Comment: @JanakNirmal, i have put the name instead of UITableViewCell, so tell us the answer